# version of database

Tags: oracle10g

Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

```
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production 
CORE    10.2.0.3.0      Production 
TNS for Solaris: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production 
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

in above result what is the database version

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say "10.2.0.3.0"

Answer (score 3):

Isnt it very obvious 10.2.0.3.0 is the version?

Answer (score 3):

Each component may have different version numbers (otherwise, why have seperate lines?), but the database itself, the main component, will be the `CORE` line.

If you're asking about the numbers; according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#Version_numbering):

> The version-numbering syntax within
>   each release follows the pattern:
>   major.maintenance.application-server.component-specific.platform-specific.